# Send a base64 encoded image to client using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to sending some JSON data to clients. In this JSON data, also an encoded image is stored (It's done by a C++ software which sends a JSON over network, using Qt and QByteArray).
Now I want to stream the data from my Node.JS server via websocket to some clients, so they can render the image on a HTML page.
So far, I'm using socket.io for the communication, but how should I manage the image streaming? 
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the "bug" and solved it.

Basically, i was streaming a cv::Mat over websocket. I was initially streaming the uchar* data without doing

```
cv::imencode(".jpg", cvMat, outputUcharVector);
```

which did the trick